# optimize for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have 2 pandas dataframes (dfA, dfB) with 2 columns each (gender, first name).
dfA are data to be cleaned (bad first name / gender) by looking for the right value in dfB.
Below is my code which works but is extremely slow for millions of pieces of data.
Is there a way to do it faster? (without using a database or other)
thank you

```
for rowIndex in range(len(dfA)):
    firstname = dfA.loc[rowIndex,'firstname']
    try:
        dfA.loc[rowIndex,'genderNew'] = dfB.loc[dfB['firstname'] == firstname].gender.values[0]
    except Exception as e:
        dfA.loc[rowIndex,'genderNew'] = "unknown"
```

Comment: In general, you should expect not to write loops in code that handles Dataframes. The *point* of using Pandas - like Numpy - is that it contains tools that handle looping over the data, taking advantage of the data structure, and avoiding Python's overhead.

Comment: That said, sometimes a Dataframe is the *wrong* tool. What you are trying to do, conceptually, with `dfB` is to *look up* a gender that corresponds to the name. This can only be an efficient operation when the name is an index for the Dataframe (and if you write to take advantage of that). Otherwise, Pandas must search every row to find the matching name. Other data structures - such as the plain old Python `dict` - are designed to let you do such lookups directly.

Comment: Have a look to the builtin `merge` function : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the job done much more efficiently:

```py
dfA.merge(dfB, on='firstname', how='left').fillna('unknown')
```

Comment: Thx, before : 5 hours, now 1.28 sec ..

Comment: Wow, that's amazing!!! (I didn't realize you said 5 hours - I misread it as 5 seconds :D)